# How to Practice Hadoop Programming?

Tags: hadoop

Just started going through Hadoop introduction videos.
How to practice it on your own?  Is there a recommended way to install on local to practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that downloading and installing Hadoop, playing with it by working examples, making lots of mistakes and being ok with that worked well for practice.

By "install on local" if you're saying "how do I install it on my local machine without using HDFS?", there's an [excellent guide here.](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to learn about Hadoop and Bigdata, look into [bigdatauniversity.com](http://bigdatauniversity.com/). Its free and they give instructions on how to install Hadoop locally on a virtual machine and/or in Amazon's Web Services. BigDataUniversity provides labs and instructions to help guide your practice. I found it helpful so far.

Answer (score 3):

Recently Cloudera launched a new platform online where you can play with Hadoop and its ecosystem as much as you want.Here you go -
[cloudera.com/live](http://cloudera.com/live)

Answer (score 3):

I have been training people on Hadoop for 2 years now. Here are my two cents.

For the learning part, I would recommend the following sources (as mentioned by others too above):

1. [Yahoo Blog](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/)
2. [Hadoop Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033448.do)
3. [HortonWorks Practice Tutorials](http://hortonworks.com/tutorials/)

And for practicing, traditionally people have been using Hadoop Virtual Machines but this approach has its downsides:

1. The VMs are huge in size for example HortonWorks' VM is 9.9 GB.
2. You might have to upgrade your RAM to 8GB.
3. Some BIOS don't allow virtualization. You might have change bios settings.
4. Some machines such as Office Desktops/Laptops may not allow installations.

My students and I too faced the these problems while. So, we setup a cluster for our students to practice Hadoop, Spark and related technologies. And we named it as [CloudxLab.com](https://cloudxlab.com/).

Answer (score 1):

...I liked bigdatauniversity.com and also noted that MapR, Hortonworks, and Cloudera all offer a downloadable environment that you can use to gain familiarity with the Hadoop operating paradigm.

In fact, if you are studying this with an eye toward working with Hadoop at an Enterprise scale, it's a good idea to explore the products that are being deployed at that level.

I've had a little chance now to explore hands-on with MapR's Hadoop environment and can commend it as a good way to looking into the matter.

---v

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/ for hadoop self paced study. Its a very comprehensive guide, step by step, from beginner to advanced level.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a virtual box that has Hadoop included but you may encounter some problems with it. I did so first when I started learning Hadoop and after several problems( IP, internet, different configs) I decided to learn with a Linux install.

You can find a tutorial here:
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Comment: Where possible, please summarise the content of external links that you reference [for example, here you might include an outline of the steps necessary to use a Linux install for this purpose]. Then if the link ever dies at least not all of the information it contained is lost. Thank you :)